# TFS - Choose what changes to checkin

Tags: tfs, version-control

I'm working on a script to help us handle the changes done to our code without having to start Visual Studio.

So far I've been able to list the changes, add them and then check them in. My understanding is that once you run the "add" command, you'll add the changes to the version control, which will then be used once you decide to check them in, meaning that anything that hasn't been added, won't be checked in.

What I'm looking for is a way to remove the changes from this list to be checked in, evne after the add command has been used. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

When you add files to version control, there will a list of pending changes. What you want is undo pending changes.

You need to use [Undo Commands](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/undo-command), which will discard one or more pending changes to files or folders.:

```
tf undo [/workspace:workspacename[;workspaceowner]]
[/recursive] itemspec [/noprompt] [/login:username,[password]]
[/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]
```